# Monitoring DOM changes on the server side with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if its possible to load a website like the [twitter search results page](http://twitter.com/search?q=Bart+Simpson#search?q=Bart%20Simpson) using node.js with jsdom and still be able to detect any changes in the DOM after the initial render.

**Example:**

**Initial page**

[image]

**Modified page**

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect what changed in the DOM tree you will need to understand the [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) Twitter's javascript code and properly intercept the events or callbacks. I don't suggest you this approach because js code that works perfectly in browser may break when using jsdom. For instance, when I was trying to do some server side scrapping with jquery I got stuck with this [bug](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues#issue/81) that in most browsers is definitely not an issue.

For the time being, what I recommend is that you consume the [Search API](http://search.twitter.com/api/) directly from Twitter which is a more straightforward approach.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the best approach is to leverage the Search API (or whatever relevant API) from Twitter to accomplish this.

But if, for some other project, you want to host a full browser environment (JS + dom + renderer) that remains alive and lets you interact with it, the PhantomJS project might work:

http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/

It hosts a WebKit instance for automation.